# a-frame + ionic addEventlistener does not register click events despite using fused cursor

Tags: ionic-framework, aframe

Hi I am trying to implement a-frame on ionic (+angular-meteor) framework and ran into a simple error. There is no click event registered when my cursor finishes fusing.

Here's the a-frame code:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title>Whatsapp Meteor</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity camera look-controls>
        <a-cursor id="cursor"a-frame fuse='true' fuseTimeout="1000">
            <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
               fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
            <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
               fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-animation>
        </a-cursor>
      </a-entity>
      <a-entity id="cube" geometry="primitive: box" material="color: blue"
                position="0 -1 -5">
      </a-entity>   
    </a-scene>
     <script>
      console.log('addEventListener script was ran');
      document.querySelector('#cube').addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log('I was clicked!');
        this.setAttribute('material', 'color', 'red');
      });
    </script> 
</body>
```

And here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfRjR.png) showing the fusing + no click event registered.

Has anyone successfully implemented ionic + aframe (preferably on angular-meteor) and can help?

Comment: update: also tried putting the same a-frame code in a new ionic1 app. same issue. I wonder if a-frame team has done any testing with ionic integration?

Comment: @ngokevin do you know if a-frame team has done Ionic integration?

Answer (score 1):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/guides/writing-a-component.html

> Note that components should be defined before `<a-scene>`

Register the component *before* you use it.

Answer (score 1):

The OP was trying to use the hardware mouse to trigger the click. In WebGL, detecting a mouse click is not as simple as a 2D page. If you want to detect using the actual mouse to click on an entity, you have to create a raycaster. Here's a component to do that for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-mouse-cursor-component

Else, you should use the gaze-based cursor component or controllers to trigger the click.

Comment: Hi I tried using gaze-based cursor to trigger the click but it does not work. Modified the question with the new code.

Comment: Also, tested the mouse-cursor-component to trigger click. Still does not work in ionic.